# setting size of JFrame using Dimension.setSize

Tags: size, jframe

I have a gui app where I need to set the size of the main JFrame to 80% of screen
width and 90% of screen height.I tried this

```
public class JFrameDemo extends JFrame{
    public JFrameDemo(String title) throws HeadlessException {
            super(title);
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

            int height = screenSize.height;
            int width = screenSize.width;
            screenSize.setSize(width*(0.80), height*(0.90));
            int newheight = screenSize.height;
            int newwidth = screenSize.width;

             //Then I put some print statements in the code
            System.out.println("height="+height);
            System.out.println("width="+width);
            System.out.println("0.80*height="+(height*0.80));
            System.out.println("0.90*width="+(width*0.90));
            System.out.println("newheight="+newheight);
            System.out.println("newwidth="+newwidth);

            this.setSize(newwidth, newheight);
            this.addWidgets();
            this.setVisible(true);
        }

        ...
}
```

Is this the correct way? I am not very familiar with gui app design..and I thought 
I could use the Dimension.setSize(double width, double height) this way.

The print statements caused this output..

```
height=768
width=1366
0.80*height=614.4
0.90*width=1229.4
newheight=692
newwidth=1093
```

Well,the newheight and newwidth are not exactly 80% or 90% of the width,height values.

Any suggestions for improvement welcome

thanks

mark

Comment: Could be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499627/why-arent-my-coordinates-matching-my-jframe-size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me some while but it simply is a mistype.

Actually you calculate 90% of width and 80% of height instead of 80% of width and 90% of height.

Swap both percentages and everything comes out fine.